# Android Development- Intents

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have recently started Android development on API version 16 (4.1). According to the tutorials that are available on developer.android.com I started to develop the app which taught me the use of Intents. The problem is that as soon as my app is loading on the Emulator it shows the error that the app had to shut down. I am giving my xml code. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Edit text"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Press"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The logcat is given below.

```
09-26 19:35:03.880: E/Trace(615): error opening trace file: No such file or directory     (2)
09-26 19:35:04.430: D/AndroidRuntime(615): Shutting down VM
09-26 19:35:04.430: W/dalvikvm(615): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  (group=0x40a13300)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.learn.training1/com.learn.training1.Training1}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at com.learn.training1.Training1.<init>(Training1.java:15)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
09-26 19:35:04.471: E/AndroidRuntime(615):  ... 11 more
09-26 19:35:32.352: I/Process(615): Sending signal. PID: 615 SIG: 9
09-26 19:39:22.460: E/Trace(664): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-26 19:39:22.820: D/AndroidRuntime(664): Shutting down VM
09-26 19:39:22.820: W/dalvikvm(664): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.learn.training1/com.learn.training1.Training1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1825)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at com.learn.training1.Training1.<init>(Training1.java:15)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
09-26 19:39:22.846: E/AndroidRuntime(664):  ... 11 more
09-26 19:40:29.130: E/Trace(712): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-26 19:40:29.431: D/dalvikvm(712): newInstance failed: Lcom/learn/training1/Training1; not accessible to Landroid/app/Instrumentation;
09-26 19:40:29.431: D/AndroidRuntime(712): Shutting down VM
09-26 19:40:29.431: W/dalvikvm(712): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.learn.training1/com.learn.training1.Training1}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
09-26 19:40:29.461: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  ... 11 more
09-26 19:43:52.020: E/Trace(760): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-26 19:43:52.110: D/dalvikvm(760): newInstance failed: Lcom/learn/training1/Training1; not accessible to Landroid/app/Instrumentation;
09-26 19:43:52.110: D/AndroidRuntime(760): Shutting down VM
09-26 19:43:52.110: W/dalvikvm(760): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.learn.training1/com.learn.training1.Training1}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
09-26 19:43:52.190: E/AndroidRuntime(760):  ... 11 more
09-26 19:47:20.550: I/Process(810): Sending signal. PID: 810 SIG: 9
```

Comment: always put your logcat (exceptions) when asking questions related to crash

Comment: Sorry. I'm really inexperienced when it comes to android. What part of the logcat do I submit? Everything?

Comment: the Error part... i mean the messages in red color. otherwise put it all :)

Comment: put the code for `Training1` too. The problem seems in the code

Comment: Yep. `Training1` code is needed, the error can be found here: `at com.learn.training1.Training1.<init>(Training1.java:15)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your activity isn't properly declared (maybe you didn't make it `public`?). You should have a file called `Training1.java` and in this file you should have something like

```
public class Training1 extends Activity {
    ...your activity code here...
}
```

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/0Gw5WHc1J6g

**EDIT: Add note**

Note: Also, you shouldn't have any constructors. The Android framework takes care of that for you.

Comment: Theres simply a `NullPointerException` at `com.learn.training1.Training1.<init>(Training1.java:15)`

Comment: @Leandros Actually, it looks like OP posted his entire logcat which has multiple attempts. My answer refers to the most recent one at 19:43:52. There were other errors (including the NPE you refer to) in other attempts at 19:35:04, 19:39:22 and 19:40:29. OP probably tried a few different things before posting his question.

Comment: Oh, I see. Don't noticed it before.